# Angular.js Module not found when grunt serve:dist, but grunt serve works fine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

So I get this error whenever I execute `grunt serve:dist` :

```
vendor.7e2420d0.js:4 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module prometheusApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module restangular due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'restangular' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

The problem is that if I run `grunt serve` it works just fine. Obviously it has to do with the `minification/uglify` process. But since the error does not say anything else I cannot figure out how to solve it.

This is my `Gruntfile`:

// Generated on 2015-04-15 using generator-angular 0.11.1

```
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    less: {
      compile: {
        options: {
          paths: ['bower_components/{,*}*.less'],
          sourceMap: true,
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main.css': '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main.less'
        }
      },
      theme_one: {
        options: {
          paths: ['bower_components/{,*}*.less']
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main.css': '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main1.less'
        }
      },
      theme_two: {
        options: {
          paths: ['bower_components/{,*}*.less']
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main.css': '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main2.less'
        }
      }
    },

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: [/*'newer:jshint:all'*/],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.less'],
        tasks: ['less:compile', 'newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
              connect().use('/app/styles', connect.static('./app/styles')),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          map: true,
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath: /\.\.\//
      },
      test: {
        devDependencies: true,
        src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
        ignorePath: /\.\.\//,
        fileTypes: {
          js: {
            block: /(([\s\t]*)\/{2}\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/{2}\s*endbower)/gi,
            detect: {
              js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
            },
            replace: {
              js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
    // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
          ]
        }, {
          //for bootstrap fonts
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
          src: ['fonts/*.*'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }, {
          //for font-awesome
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/font-awesome',
          src: ['fonts/*.*'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          flatten: true,
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/translations/*',
          ],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/translations'
        }, {
          expand: true,
          flatten: true,
          src: [
            'bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/*',
            'bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/*'
          ],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts'
        }, {
          expand: true,
          flatten: true,
          src: [
            'divshot.json',
          ],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {

    if (target === 'dist') return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);

    var tasks = ['clean:server'];
    if (target === 'theme_one') tasks.push('less:theme_one');
    else if (target === 'theme_two') tasks.push('less:theme_two');
    else tasks.push('less:compile'), console.log("tema elegido: " + target);

    tasks = tasks.concat(['wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer:server',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch']);

    grunt.task.run(tasks, 'connect:dist:keepalive');
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'less:compile',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build:theme:one', [
    'clean:dist',
    'less:theme_one',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build:theme:two', [
    'clean:dist',
    'less:theme_two',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
};
```

I have no clue what could be wrong. How could I debug this error?

Comment: How are you doing the angular dependency injection?

Comment: Like this: `service(['a', 'b', 'c', ..., function (a,b,c) {...}])`

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm having the same issue with a different library.

Answer (score 0):

Angular finds the controller's dependencies from the names of arguments found in the constructor function. When you minify the JavaScript code for PrometheusApp, all of its function arguments get minified, and the Angular is not be able to find the modules.

There is a couple of ways to go about doing this.

1. inline annotation
2. $inject Property
3. Grunt plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ng-annotate plugin.

I would recommend using the $inject Property Annotation

This annotation allows the minifiers to rename the function parameters. When using this annotation functions need to be annotated with the $inject property. This is an array of service names to inject for this module.

```
var PrometheusApp = function($scope, customComponent) {
  // Do Stuff here
}
PrometheusApp.$inject = ['$scope', 'customComponent'];
```

This is obviously a preference, all three options listed above will work just find. I prefer using the $inject Annotation as I fell its more explicit.

Take a look at the Angular documentation for dependency injection

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

Try removing uglifyjs from your usemin process like below, to find out if restangular has been included in your vendor.js file. + Could I see your bower.json file too?

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    flow: {
      html: {
        steps: {
          js: ['concat'],
          css: ['cssmin']
        },
        post: {}
      }
    }
  }
},
```